# Is "Why?" (said in a neutral tone) considered to be an aggressive word in English language?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs, questions, offensive-language

I am a non-native English speaker although I lived in UK for 5+ years.
I had a conversation with a colleague today and he claims that using "why?" in conversation is an aggressive thing to do.

My understanding was that "why?" is asking for reasoning behind the thing and is neutral.

**Is "Why?" (said in a neutral tone) considered to be an aggressive word in English language?**

Comment: The use of any word can be "aggressive" depending on the context and tone in which the word is said.

Comment: It's not the word that's aggressive, it's the one-word question, "Why?"  It implies that you doubt what the other person is saying.

Comment: @Greybeard in neutral tone I mean :)

Comment: I disagree with your colleague. The one-word question "why?" certainly *can* come across as aggressive, but that's not the same as claiming that it simply *is*.

Comment: It certainly depends on context. If you're asked to do something and respond "why?", it could be argumentative or obstructive or insubordinate, although it might be reasonable if you genuinely need to know why. (Imagine if you go into a bakery and ask for a loaf of bread and the baker says "why?") If someone says something obvious or trivial and you ask "why?" it could be argumentative or obnoxious ("I need a drink of water." "Why?"). And there are ways of being more polite, such as "Could you tell me why?"

Comment: @StuartF good points and examples raised here. The issue I believe, is that the person who is receiving the why is then stuck with half the picture. They have no concrete idea why the baker responded the way the baker did. Let's tweak the situation a bit. Let's say the person already bought a loaf, coming back for another. The baker could ask "why", but it would be better to ask "oh, was there something wrong with the previous loaf?" Or even a cheeky "are you sure you don't want more before you go?". I feel that in the same scenario, "could you tell me why" though polite, is still confusing.

Comment: Resistance is futile. Context is everything. And here, **that means the suprasegmental feature known as speech intonation or tone**. Of all the features of English that are misunderstood, intonation, stress and tone figure high on the list. And of course, here, we can't really show that. Too bad sound files are not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might depend on the context, but more often than not, it sounds accusatory, which may lead to conflict and aggression. Usually the recipient of a why question takes it "personally"

There are alternative ways of asking a "why" question that better reveal the intent of the person asking.

For example, if you said something and someone said one of the following:

- why?
- why would you do that?
- why would you think that?
- why are you always like this?

It might sound like what you're doing is wrong. They are questioning your motives in a way. And you might go into defence mode.

On the other hand, if they asked instead:

- how come?
- what led you to that decision?
- how did you come to that conclusion?
- (this one's a bit tricky as it sounds like things have already escalated)

It seems like the asker is really trying to understand and is genuinely curious, rather than accusatory.

More often than not the asker doesn't want conflict, they just want to know the reasons behind the actions, or the things that led up to them. It is definitely takes more effort, but taking the time to find alternatives will lead to less conflicts in my opinion.

Comment: @psmears Thanks for the edit 